# MySQL: Temporary incremental column

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I am trying to create some sort of 'high score' - I will have to gather all users' total experience, and total level information from the database, but I want to add a temporary MySQL column to the query (which will be an integer), so I can know right away what their ranking is.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT characters_statistics.total_level, 
       characters_statistics.total_exp, 
       characters.username 
FROM characters_statistics 
INNER JOIN characters ON characters.id = characters_statistics.master_id 
ORDER BY total_exp DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @rownum = 0; 
Select sub.*, sub.rank as Rank
FROM
(
   Select *,  (@rownum:=@rownum+1) as rank
   FROM   YourTableName
) sub
```